# Importing Font Awesome icons that have a dash ("-") in their name

Tags: html, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I am using React.js to make a portfolio website.  I decided to go with Font Awesome icons since I love the look of them.  However when I go to import any icon that has that dash in the name, I can't figure out how to import it.  Here's my code so far (for importing):

```react
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

// All these are single name icons
import {faPython} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faPython";
import {faJs} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faJs";
import {faReact} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faReact";
import {faCuttlefish} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faCuttlefish";

// This one is named "rectangle-code"
import {faRectangleCode} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faRectangleCode";
```

I get this error:
[image: portfolio importing error]

I can't import it using dashes in the name, so how do I import this icon without any errors?

EDIT: Click [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/rectangle-code?s=solid) to view the icon on Font Awesome's website

Comment: try ``import faRectangleCode from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faRectangleCode";``

Comment: `import { faRectangleCode } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem!

[image]

You're attempting to use a pro icon - it doesn't exist in the free icon packs.

(Edit: for future reference, a good way to debug import problems like this is to `cd` inside the `@fortawesome` directory in your terminal, and then use something like https://github.com/junegunn/fzf to look for the file you're looking for. That's what I did before realizing the icon doesn't exist in the free version.)

Comment: THANK YOU! I couldn't figure it out for the longest time.  I am now using the "free" filter when I search for things.